# Button not working to show mobile menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have just started to learn `J-Query` and I'm trying to implement a simple click event into my webpage, which is when you click a button it will open the mobile-nav.

This button works when I select the header for example it will hide the header but wont show the mobile-nav?

p.s I'm copying the DICE homepage just for learning purposes as I know I'm using copyrighted media ;).

I think it could be to do with that Im hiding the mobile-nav in my `CSS` so the `J-query` cant toogle/show it.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    nav{
    justify-content: space-around;    
    }
    
    .bars{
    display:block; 
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    } 
    
    
    ul{
    display: none !important;    
    }
    
    
    .mobile-nav{
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left:-110px;
    top:70px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color:black;
    }
    
    .mobile-nav li{
    height: 50px;    
    }
    
    .mobile-nav a{
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 
    <title>Dice</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(function(){
        
    $('.bars').on('click',function(){
        $('.mobile-nav').show();
    });                    
                        
                        
    
                        
                        
    }); //End of code?//
    
    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav>
    <img src="dice-logotype-black.png">
    <button class="bars">
    <ul class="mobile-nav">
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">GAMES</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">JOBS</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>    
    </ul>
    </button>    
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">GAMES</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">JOBS</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>    
    </ul></nav>
    </header> 
<div class="global-container">    
    <div class="video"><video src="dicemovie3-1.mp4" autoplay loop></video>   
<div class="text"><h1>We share the passion to create something extraordinary.</h1>
<button>DISCOVER OUR CULTURE</button><button id="button-2">READ ABOUT OUR GAMES</button>       
        </div> 
    </div>       
</div> 
<div class="square-images">
<div class="square-1"></div>    
<div class="square-2"></div> 
<div class="square-3"></div>     
</div>  
<div class="about-dice-wrapper"><div><h2>MORE THAN COMPUTER SCREENS</h2>
<p>DICE is the award-winning developer of the Battlefield franchise and games like Mirror’s Edge.
We are situated in the world’s most picturesque cities, Stockholm, 
Sweden and in the vibrant city of Los Angeles, USA.</p>
<button>About Dice</button></div></div>    
<div class="tweet-wrapper"><div>
<img src="tweet.jpg-thumb">
<p>Meet DICE today! Head to Stockholm's Nationalmuseum at 18:00 & learn about character design: https://t.co/WGUbkFNjay https://t.co/0SrHr38HiH<br> @EA_DICE</p>    
    
    </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully someone can give me some insight into this issue.

Comment: try to avoid set show/hide in this context. Use toggleClass and by css make visible or hidden your menu

Comment: I did attempt to use the j-query to change the css to display:block but it didn't work. I will have to look into toggleClass as I'm very green with J-query :)

Answer (score 1):

The most simple (according to my knowledge) solution for animated mobile navigation:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('nav').hide();
  $('.show_nav').click(function(){
    $('nav').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
      .show_nav {
        padding: 1em 1.4em;
        background: #ddd; }

      nav {
        background: #111; }
        nav ul {
          list-style: none;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0; }
          nav ul li {
            color: #fff;
            padding: 1em 1.4em; }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <button class="show_nav">show nav</button>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>Hello world!</li>
            <li>Hello world!</li>
            <li>Hello world!</li>
            <li>Hello world!</li>
            <li>Hello world!</li>
            <li>Hello world!</li>
            <li>Hello world!</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Obviously style as you want it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
$(".bars").click(function() {
 $(".mobile-nav").show();
});
```

```css
.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="bars">Click me</button>

    <ul class="mobile-nav">
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">GAMES</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">JOBS</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>    
    </ul>
```

Although the use of toggleClass will be more useful.

```js
 $(".bars").click(function(event) {
  $(".mobile-nav").toggleClass('opened');
 });
```

```css
.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
}

.opened {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="bars">Click to toggle</button>

<ul class="mobile-nav">
  <li>Blabla</li>
  <li>Blabla</li>
  <li>Blabla</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry that was my original attempt having the </button> outside the mobile-nav still doesn't work. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Can't get either of the examples to work in my code I even pasted the show example and its still not working?    Also for the toggleclass so do I need to link that .opened to anything in my html? The button works if I select any other element?

Comment: Are you sure you are putting CSS in the exact same order and the div is not conflicting with anything else? Bring developer`s console up and see if anything is reporting back an error

Comment: I'm getting no error's in the chrome developer console.Only place I have .mobile-nav is under  @media screen. Just checked and I need to write display:block !important to get it to appear? Could that be an issue.

Comment: Place below the .opened div

Comment: I just wrote it in code pen and I got the button working but still cant get it working in my work.....thank you for helping I now know about toggleClass at least :)